# Rabo Omnikassa support for exp:resso store

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I bought a license of Exp:resso Store, with the idea that it supports Rabo OmniKassa payment gateway, as mentioned by Exp:resso itself in there [release notes](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_1_6_0).

Now I want to setup the payment gateway information and notice that it is not available in store 2.x.

So I contacted Exp:resso about this and they said that the payment gateway was dropped as of version 2.x. But they also told me that will look at it at try to re-implement it.

That's what they said 6 weeks ago. But radio silence since that last e-mail.

I e-mailed them a couple of times, but only receiving a default answer but no real answer. In my opinion, the support is very bad voor Exp:resso store.

Hopefully, they well fix my issue. But until then, maybe I have to fix it myself. But how will I be able to do so, of does anyone already have done this? Implementing support for Rabo OmniKassa.

Comment: i don't know if it's an answer, but you could try to get into contact with Bas van Ginkel (www.ditiserg.nl). he had an omnikassa plugin built a while ago

Comment: Any updates on this?? I would be very interested if anyone made any progress on this..

Answer (score 1):

Usually additional gateways are sponsored before they are developed so you could talk to them about sponsoring the creation of the new gateway.

The [docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/store_20_upgrade_notes.html#payments_library) also mention that Store 2 payment library was rewritten and that not all gateways are supported.

> Most officially supported gateways have been included, but any
>   third-party gateways will need to be rewritten in the new format.

Having said that Store uses [Omnipay](https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay) which is an open source payment library so you could easily develop your own Rabo Omnikassa gateway using their [API](https://www.rabobank.nl/bedrijven/producten/betalen_en_ontvangen/alle_producten/rabo_omnikassa/). You can look at the included gateways to see how the payment gateway should be structured.

If all else fails they do have a have a return period, and would probably make an exception if you have passed that threshold.